# SQL count counting twice

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with an SQL statement, not overly experienced with SQL and have come to a dead end. I'm trying to return a count of items picked and a count of items to be picked. The statement is working in the fact that it returns a count but the count is double what it should be i.e 1 comes in as 2 etc. Can anyone point out what I am missing?

```
SELECT b.BoxID AS BoxID
    ,p.productCode AS ProductCode
    ,ol.ProductID AS ProductID
    ,COUNT(OI.Picked) AS PickCount
    ,COUNT(OI.[Identity]) AS NeededCount
    ,shortDesc
    ,OL.PickLocation
    ,OL.PickZone
FROM OrderLine OL
INNER JOIN Products P ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN OrderItem OI ON OL.[Identity] = OI.OrderLineIdentity
INNER JOIN Boxes b ON OI.BoxID = b.BoxID
INNER JOIN PickingLog pl ON b.BoxID = pl.BoxID
WHERE B.BoxBarcode = @BoxBarcode
GROUP BY b.BoxID
    ,p.productCode
    ,ol.ProductID
    ,shortDesc
    ,OL.PickLocation
    ,PL.PickingEnd
    ,OL.PickZone
ORDER BY OL.PickZone
```

Some sample results

The numbers in bold are items picked and items needed. These should be 1 where they are currently 2 and 2 where they are currently 4.

```
5168    A264        27018 **2     2**   Colour: Black   A04D021 A
5168    A946-41.5   27523 **2     2**   Size 41.5. UK Size 7/8. US Size: M8/W10 A02C049 A
5168    A978        27594 **2     2**   Size: One Size  A03C022 A
5168    E915        33157   0   **4**   Red. 100% cotton. Size: 30 x 20".   B03E024 B
5168    A026-M      26919   0   **2**   Waist size: M (34" - 36")   D03E019 D
```

Comment: you should show the sample data and the expected result

Comment: It's likely one of your `JOIN`s causing the issue, but without seeing the data, I can't say.  What DBMS are you using?  MySQL is not the same as SQL Server.

Comment: Perhaps... `count (Distinct OI.Picked) as PickCount count (distinct Oi.[identity]) as NeededCount` as I believe the joins are adversely affecting your counts.  though a better approach may be to subselect to aggregate the counts first then join on the table keys.

Comment: It really grinds my gears when people don't stick to one text formatting style

Comment: The main issue I'm seeing is a disparity between the aliases. I didn't see a join to an alias of OL until I checked again for the `FROM` keyword, which should be on a different line for clarity, and the capitalization of the aliases is not maintained from declaration to use. If your shift key is too hard to use consistently, don't capitalize anything. If you can't be bothered to hit the same key sequence from item to item, shorten it (from oi to just o). That may fix your errors, unless this is just a miscopy.

Comment: xQbert that solved the issue, thanks

Comment: CSS not everyone is perfect, I asked for help not abuse. Didn't realise this site had turned into facebook with keyboard warriors. I try to keep things consistant but mistakes do happen. And anyways SQL is not case sensitive so doesnt affect the outcome of the query.

Comment: OP, code formatting exists for a reason, CSS wasn't abusing you in any way. @RyanMcKinney

Comment: Even if SQL is not case sensitive, you should keep the same formatting for **good practice** It makes code easier to read, easier to understand, easier to follow @RyanMcKinney

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should troubleshoot an issue like this. Choose one row that is giving a duplicate, say BoxId = 5, then you run a statement without the grouping and counts, looking only at that ID

```
 SELECT b.BoxID as BoxID, p.productCode as ProductCode, ol.ProductID 
   , OI.Picked, OI.[Identity],  shortDesc, OL.PickLocation, OL.PickZone
 from OrderLine OL 
 join Products P on ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
 join OrderItem OI on OL.[Identity] = OI.OrderLineIdentity
 join Boxes b on OI.BoxID = b.BoxID
 join PickingLog pl on b.BoxID = pl.BoxID
 WHERE B.BoxBarcode = @BoxBarcode AND B.Boxid=5
```

Then see how many rows it returns. Sometimes, you'll see duplicates here because you have more than one different record here where you didn't think there were different records. Then you can adjust your code or expectations accordingly. Other times, you will see what look like duplicate *identical* records. In that case, add a primary key from each joined table to your selected columns. Likely, one of those tables has two entries you are joining.  Maybe pickinglog has multiple entries but you only want the one with a specific flag (current=1, for example). Once you find out where that problem is, you can add an AND current=1 to the ON clause for that particular join.